# How to pass java script array to Controller action using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I hava a javascript array in my Razor view, and I am calling an GET action of controller from my MVC view using $.ajax. What should be the parameter type of the Controller action that will accept the Javascript array passed from view.
I tried to keep it as "object", but it is showing it as "[object]" only and showing no properties at all.
Any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: You should include some code.

Comment: yes, agreed.. but its difficult to separate out only the code of interest. if anyone having instant idea..

Comment: convert that `{object}` to an `[array]` before passing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It completely depends upon the **type of the values in your array**.

Say, if you have an array of integers, like this:

```
var intArray = [1,2,3,4]
```

Then, in your controller, you'd have a `List<int>` as your parameter type, the Controller is clever enough to figure out the conversion for you.

However, if you're wanting something more advanced, which I'm guessing you are, such as:

```
var customArray = [{hello: "world", foo: "bar"}]
```

Then it's best to create a custom object in .NET, with `hello` and `foo` as properties, such as:

```
public CustomObject {
   public string hello { get; set; }
   public string foo { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use `CustomObject`, or `List<CustomObject>` as your parameter type and the Controller will map the properties for you... like magic.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass it in ajax and add `traditional: true,`

```
var ids = [0,1,2,3];

$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "Home")',
   type: 'POST',
   traditional: true,
   data: { array: ids },
   ...
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int[] array){}
```

For object array

```
var objs = JSON.stringify(your_objects);

$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "Home")',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { array: objs },
   ...
```

controller

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(List<YourObjectType> array){}
```

Check [HERE](http://telldontask.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/posting-an-array-of-complex-types-using-jquery-json-to-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: thanks, this just worked out for me, however, I have a similar thing but here now my Javascript array is actually a key-value pair..